# Puzzling: If statement with <= not working as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging

This is probably obvious, but I cannot see it...

```
NSLog(@"nthObject = %i, [mutableFetchResults count] - 1 = %i", nthObject, [mutableFetchResults count] - 1);
if (nthObject <= [mutableFetchResults count] - 1) {
    MyObject *myObject = [mutableFetchResults objectAtIndex:nthObject];
```

The count of mutableFetchResults is zero, so [mutableFetchResults count] - 1 = -1 and nthObject is 0. This is proven by the Log.

nthObject is an int passed into the method.

So the of statement should be saying if (0 <= -1) and therefore not firing the MyObject *myObject = [mutableFetchResults objectAtIndex:nthObject] line, but it does which then causes a crash as its trying to access an empty array.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Just a quick note, I'd make it < instead of <=, and get rid of the -1. Makes it easier to read.

Comment: @Mannimarco: and fixes the problem, I think?

Comment: @Jesse Naugher: You're right, that would. Wasn't sure if Count was an unsigned integer, so wasn't going to guess.. I don't do objective C/iPhone development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming that `mutableFetchResults` is an `NSMutableArray` (a subclass of `NSArray`).  The `count` member is an `NSUInteger` which is unsigned, so `[mutableFetchResults count] - 1` doesn't go negative - it wraps around to become a very large number.

Change your test to be:

```
if (nthObject < [mutableFetchResults count])
```

Comment: `if (([[NSArray array] count]-1) >0) {
        NSLog(@"greater than zero");
    } `//outputs greater Than Zero

Answer (score 2):

Is `[mutableFetchResults count]` an unsigned int? The "%i" in the format string says to print it as a signed int, but that doesn't mean it is...

Answer (score 1):

`[mutableFetchResults count]` returns an NSUInteger.

If count is 0 then 0 - 1 on an NSUInteger will not be -1, it will 'wrap' around and be a massive number.

Answer (score 1):

[mutableFetchResults count] likely is [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArra), so it yields an unsigned integer. It will wrap around to the max value of an unsigned integer , and your `i` will also be promoted to an unsigned type.

You comparison ends up as something like (0 < 0xffffffff).